# Thinking Sphinx wild card search and fuzzy operator not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to implement a full text for set of models. I heard the power of sphinx in its indexing speed and search time. But wild card searches and nearest word match ( Levenshtein distance) are not working in this.

```
    Post.search 'kar' 
returns no results while 
    Post.search 'karthik' 
returns 10 results matching the exact string. I even tried with star parameter
    Post.search 'kar' , :star => true
 which returns zero results.
```

I tried with all combinations like '`kar*`' , '`krathik~`' , etc in lucene flavored full text search engines  and it works fine. Am I missing any optional parameters or does sphinx still lacks this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added something like the following to your config/sphinx.yml file?

```
development:
min_infix_len: 2
sql_host: localhost
sql_user: root
```

Comment: Yes my config file looks like this : production:
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 3
port: 3312
address: 127.0.0.1
mem_limit: 512M
max_children: 300
max_matches: 100000
seamless_rotate: 1
preopen_indexes: 1
query_log_file: "RAILS_ROOT/log/searchd.query.log"
searchd_log_file: "RAILS_ROOT/log/searchd.log"
pid_file: "RAILS_ROOT/log/searchd.production.pid"
searchd_file_path: "RAILS_ROOT/db/sphinx/development/"

Comment: but this don't include  Levenshtein distance rite?

Comment: min_infix_len only sets the infix length cutoff to allow indexing of infixes. Not related to Levenshtein distance, but having indexed infixes "allows to implement wildcard searching by 'start*', '*end', and '*middle*' wildcards", via http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-min-infix-len.html